# Managing NA values in data frames while running if else loop

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I have two data frames where I want to run this code.
Both data frames are of the same size.
`psd.csv` has some values that are blanks.

The objective is that I want `NA` to remain as `NA` in the data frame `nmsd` too.

This code is showing the following error :

> Error in
>
> if (psd[i, j] == "NA") nmsd[i, j] = psd[i, j] else if (psd[i,  :   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

```
   for(j in 1:500){
     for(i in 1:3418){
       if(psd[i,j]=="NA")
         nmsd[i,j] = psd[i,j]
       else if(psd[i,j]>=0 && psd[i,j]<=0.3)
         nmsd[i,j]=psd[i,j]+0.3*(1-psd[i,j])
       else if(psd[i,j]>0.3 && psd[i,j]<=0.4) 
         nmsd[i,j]=psd[i,j]+0.1*(1-psd[i,j])
       else if(psd[i,j]>0.4 && psd[i,j]<=0.6) 
         nmsd[i,j]=psd[i,j]+0.2*(1-psd[i,j])
       else if(psd[i,j]>0.6 && psd[i,j]<=0.9) 
         nmsd[i,j]=psd[i,j]+0.3*(1-psd[i,j])
       else(psd[i,j]>0.9 && psd[i,j]<=1) 
         nmsd[i,j]=psd[i,j]+0.1*(1-psd[i,j])
          }
         }
```

Comment: You may need `ifelse` and also change `&&` to `&`

Comment: Instead of `psd[i,j]=="NA"` you should use `is.na(psd[i, j])`.

Answer (score 0):

The error, as stated in the comments, comes from the `NA` check: you have to use `is.na()` instead of `=="NA"`. Furthermore, in the last `else` an `if` is missing.

However, you should vectorize your calculation. See that your `nmsd` is defined as `psd + coeff*(1-psd)`. The only thing is that `coeff` depends on the interval of the relative element of `psd`. We can use `findInterval` to find the proper `coeff`, without having to deal with a bunch of `if else` conditions.

We mock some data:

```
set.seed(5678)
psd<-matrix(runif(500*3418),nrow=3418,ncol=500)
#we insert some NA value
psd[sample(length(psd),1000)]<-NA
```

Then we state the extrema of the intervals and the relative coefficient:

```
intervals<-c(0,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.9)
coeff<-c(0.3,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1)
```

Then, the result is simply:

```
res<-psd+coeff[findInterval(psd,intervals)]*(1-psd)
```

We can calcuate the final result with the `if else` (I modified your code to make it work):

```
nmsd<-matrix(0,nrow=3418,ncol=500)
for(j in 1:500){
     for(i in 1:3418){
       if(is.na(psd[i,j]))
         nmsd[i,j] = psd[i,j]
       else if(psd[i,j]>=0 && psd[i,j]<=0.3)
         nmsd[i,j]=psd[i,j]+0.3*(1-psd[i,j])
       else if(psd[i,j]>0.3 && psd[i,j]<=0.4) 
         nmsd[i,j]=psd[i,j]+0.1*(1-psd[i,j])
       else if(psd[i,j]>0.4 && psd[i,j]<=0.6) 
         nmsd[i,j]=psd[i,j]+0.2*(1-psd[i,j])
       else if(psd[i,j]>0.6 && psd[i,j]<=0.9) 
         nmsd[i,j]=psd[i,j]+0.3*(1-psd[i,j])
       else if(psd[i,j]>0.9 && psd[i,j]<=1) 
         nmsd[i,j]=psd[i,j]+0.1*(1-psd[i,j])
    }
}
```

And see that the result is the same, but the vectorized solution is much faster and cleaner:

```
identical(res,nmsd)
#[1] TRUE
```